# connected secondry drive how to increase /home value

Tags: 12.10

I had connected secondary hard drive in my computer, my primary hard drive value is full so how to increase the value of my /home partition .

Comment: If you are sure that the secondary drive is mounted and visible in your file system (e.g. by entering `df -h`), and you have your home directory safely backed up, then turn to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) official article from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is not difficult and is explained in detail here: [Installing A New Hard Drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive)

To summarize the key steps.

- First you need to find out what the system has called your hard drive

`sudo lshw -C disk`

the output will look something like this

```
 *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: IC25N040ATCS04-0
       vendor: Hitachi
       physical id: 0
       bus info: ide@0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: CA4OA71A
       serial: CSH405DCLSHK6B
       size: 37GB
       capacity: 37GB
```

Note the logical name for your new drive in this case `/dev/sdb`

- partition the drive

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`

Select <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> for new partition

Select <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> for a primary one and finally

<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If it asks about the first cylinder, just type "1" and enter. (We are making 1 partition to use the whole disk, so it should start at the beginning.)

Once complete <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write the partition table.

- Format the drive

`sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1`

- Create a mount point

`mkdir /home/$USER/MyData`

- Setup automouunt

`gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

and add this line (replacing username) with your username

```
 /dev/sdb1    /home/username/MyData   ext4    defaults     0        2
```

Save

- For these changes to take effect either enter `sudo mount -a` or reboot and you should be good to go.

--

Alternatively you can mount your new drive as your '\home' folder in a similar way